# Makefile ignore the prerequisites of a prerequisite

Tags: python, makefile, continuous-integration

I've got a quite specific problem. I'm trying to distribute a python package (egg) and to make the life for the developers easier I've developed a `Makefile`.

My distribution contains the Code (Python source files) and some build Dokumentation (HTML, PDF, ...).

Thus, I've got these targets in my `Makefile`:

```
doc/admin/html: doc/admin/src/*
    echo "Build the HTML doc..."

doc/admin/pdf: doc/admin/src/*
    echo "Build the PDF doc..."

doc: doc/admin/html doc/admin/pdf

$(PACKAGE).egg: doc/admin/html doc/admin/pdf src/*
    echo "Build the egg..."

egg: $(PACKAGE).egg
```

This works well so far. As soon as a developer changes either a source file or the documentation, he/she can rebuild the documentation with the `doc` target and/or the whole distribution with the `egg` target.

Now my problem: I've got another target `test_egg` to test the distribution.
Currently my target is defined as follows:

```
test_egg: $(PACKAGE).egg
    echo "Test the egg..."
```

This target should be executed either by the developer AND by a CI.
The problem is: During the CI, the `$(PACKAGE).egg` file will be build by another job and then transported to the test environment (I'm using the gitlab-ci). Thus, in this test environment the `$(PACKAGE).egg` exists, but not the `doc/admin/html` and `doc/admin/pdf` folders for the documentation. They arn't needed for this target, as they are only intermediate files for the egg.

My Question now is: How do I define the `test_egg` target such that it executes 
without trying to rebuild the documentation when the `$(PACKAGE).egg` exists?

I know, I could define the `doc/admin/*` folders as `INTERMEDIATE`, but this would prevent the developer from building just the documentation using the `doc` target.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best is to avoid declaring `$(PACKAGE).egg` as a prerequisite of `test_egg`. There are several ways to do that.

1. You can use make conditionals to instantiate different recipes for `test_egg`:

   ```
   test_egg:
   ifeq ($(wildcard $(PACKAGE).egg),)
       $(error Ooops!)
   else
       echo "Test the egg..."
   endif
   ```
2. You can use the make `if` function in the recipe:

   ```
   test_egg:
       $(if $(wildcard $(PACKAGE).egg),,$(error Ooops!))
       echo "Test the egg..."
   ```
3. You can use the shell's conditionals:

   ```
   test_egg:
       [ -e $(PACKAGE).egg ] || { echo "Ooops!" && exit -1; }
       echo "Test the egg..."
   ```

In all cases, if `$(PACKAGE).egg` does not exist, the `test_egg` goal will fail with an error message. If `$(PACKAGE).egg` exists the `test_egg` goal will be run but `$(PACKAGE).egg` will not be updated, even if it is outdated.

Example of use:

```
$ cat Makefile
PACKAGE = foo
$(PACKAGE).egg: a b
    @echo "Making $@..."
    @touch $@
a b:
    @touch $@
.PHONY: test_egg
test_egg:
ifeq ($(wildcard $(PACKAGE).egg),)
    $(error $(PACKAGE).egg not found, please build it first)
else
    @echo "Test the egg..."
endif
$ make test_egg
Makefile:10: *** foo.egg not found, please build it first.  Stop.
$ make foo.egg
Making foo.egg...
$ make test_egg
Test the egg...
$ touch a b
$ make test_egg
Test the egg...
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but this does not work. It is checking whether to rebuild the egg anyway.. `Considering target file 'test_egg'.
 File 'test_egg' does not exist.
  Considering target file 'cs.erp-10.1.1-py2.7.egg'.
    Considering target file 'doc/admin/html'.`

Comment: As either way the developer needs to rember to build the egg, I gave up an removed the dependency to the egg. This target is for CI, and in CI I know that there is an egg and if not, I want it to fail anyway.. But still, thanks! Will accept the answer, as this might be the right one for others

Comment: You're right, I did not fully understand your problem and order-only prerequisites are not what you need. They are rebuilt when needed but this does not force the target that depends on them to be also rebuilt. It is not what you need. Edited my answer with a better option.